Generate as short as possible boolean formula from a given truth table
Given a truth table, maybe 3-vars, 5-vars or even 10-vars, i can write its formula in DNF or CNF, and simplify it using K-Map or Quine-McCluskey algorithm. But it is based on {NOT, AND, OR}.
Now the question is, how can i write a shorter formula from the truth table, based on {NOT, AND, OR, XOR, IMPLY, XNOR}?

Would be great if you would include some attempts of your own or at least ideas.

Maybe look at K-Map or Quine-McCluskey, see how they use NOT, AND, OR, and try to generalize that to the other operations.
I realize that this is pretty obvious, but at least it is a place to start.

For the 3-variable case, you could just brute-force all possible functions.  Though, that might take longer with 5 variables, and be impractical with 10.

This is boolean expression minimization.  In general, it is hard.  You should not expect to find any general step-by-step procedure that always works and doesn't take too long.  I believe it is known to be $\Sigma_2^P$-complete, and thus NP-hard, in general.
If you need to solve it in practice, practical methods are probably to do some kind of search over formula.  You can probably use a SAT solver to speed up the search.
You can read about logic optimization, the minimum circuit size problem (and https://mcsp.work/).
